Select different error channel and reformulate the weight of error mechanism based on the measurement results
In stim:

Can I select a different error channel based on the measurement results of heralded erasure errors?

For example:
R 0 1

HERALDED_PAULI_CHANNEL_1(0.1, 0, 0, 0) 0

if rec[-1] == 1:
#error channel 1
PAULI_CHANNEL_2(pix1, piy1, piz1, pxi1, pxx1, pxy1, pxz1, pyi1, pyx1, pyy1, pyz1, pzi1, pzx1, pzy1, pzz1) 0 1

elif rec[-1] == 0:
#error channel 2
PAULI_CHANNEL_2(pix2, piy2, piz2, pxi2, pxx2, pxy2, pxz2, pyi2, pyx2, pyy2, pyz2, pzi2, pzx2, pzy2, pzz2) 0 1


How can I reformulate the weight of error mechanism(the probability of the error) in circuit.detector_error_model() based on the measurement results from a single sampler?

Referring to the previously mentioned example, if the measurement results of heralded erasure error are confirmed as true, I will revise the probability of all error mechanisms about error channel 1 to be 0.5; if they are false, no revision will take place.
If I am able to accomplish that, how can I achieve the same in Sinter?

There is currently no way for a stim circuit to express conditional errors like this.
You can use stim.FlipSimulator to apply custom error logic while running a simulation. In stim~=1.14.dev, sinter has a new class sinter.Sampler that you can implement, to easily run these custom simulations across multiple cores. Because the error mechanisms are not written down in the circuit, they won't show up in the detector error model for the decoder to see. So you will also need to customize your decoding logic to account for these errors.
